# Cms integration with existing website

Tags: html, css, wordpress, joomla, content-management-system

Okay, I figured that this would be the place to ask about Content Management Sysetems.

Basically, I run a website, www.com and nobody updates it because it is too complicated. Is there any way I could use a CMS such as Wordpress or Joomla to only update certain DIV's so that I do not have to redesign the entire site? Or is there any systems that people would recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try http://grabaperch.com/

It is really simple and you can use you existing pages. Just select editable areas and you are done!

It's not free, but the price is not bad.

Another similar option is http://www.cushycms.com

Answer (score 2):

Well... you could probably use a CMS to create content, but your CMS template would basically be empty so you are only outputting the content and not the whole page design.  Then in your current site, you could just include the CMS content files in the DIVs where you want them to display.

However, you would be much better off in the long run spending the time creating a template that matches your site now and use the full features of the CMS.  It wouldn't really be too much more work.  You'd take the HTML you have now and convert that to a template for the CMS you choose.  Most are similar in that you have a master HTML file/template that you layout all your designs, etc, then replace portions with CMS content such as Navbar, Sidebars, Main Content, Footer, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a CMS such as WordPress and then creating a theme based on your existing website HTML to provide the header, menu & footer.

The ease of editing content will be a big benefit to your content authors, and the ease of administering everything else will be a big benefit to you.

Having a quick look over your existing site, most of this could be done with a few WordPress pages, and a handful of plugins (e.g. a contact form plugin, something like AddThis for Google +1 buttons etc)

Comment: If you want to pursue the embedding, this link might provide some help, but I'd really recommend going the full WordPress route: http://www.corvidworks.com/articles/wordpress-content-on-other-pages